# Find general solution of series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm trying to find the series solution of:

$$2x^2y''+3xy'-(x^2+1)y=0$$

so far I found the indicial polynomial: $2k^2+k-1=0$ , so $k=1/2$ and $k=-1$.

Then I found the recurrence relation: $$a_n=\frac{a_{n-2}}{(2n+2k-1)(n+k)-1}$$

Now if I plug in $k=-1$: $$a_n=\frac{a_{n-2}}{2n^2+5n+2}$$

And if I plug in $k=1/2$: $$a_n=\frac{a_{n-2}}{2n^2+n-1}$$

I now $a_0$ and $a_1$ are free variables. But I'm confuse in how do I find the 2 independent series solutions? How do I find the coefficients?

Thanks!

Comment: $a_0=0, a_1=1$ gives on solution and $a_0=1, a_1=0$ gives another solution.

Comment: But if $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ are free why choose $0,1$ and $1,0$ respectively? Aren't there infinitely many solutions?

Comment: I don't really understand as it looks like you have found the general solution, i.e. the set of solutions expressed as a recurrence relation.

Comment: **HINT:** Try a change of variable $z=\frac{-ix}{\sqrt{2}}$ and you should reach a familiar equation.

Comment: @K.defaoite. There is another one which is doable before this good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series for $k=-1$ and $k=\frac12$ are different objects, it is a little bit disingenuous to use the same symbols for their coefficients in close proximity. In both series the coefficient $a_0$ is free, this is the result of solving the indicial equation. The next equation only contains $a_1$ with a non-zero coefficient, so that $a_1=0$ in both cases, implying that all odd-index coefficients are zero. This means that you only get two independent solutions.

Comment: How do I know each terms are odd or even? Do I need to make an assumption?

Comment: Indices $n=0,2,4,6,..$ are even, indices $n=1,3,5,7,...$ in $a_n$ are odd. This has nothing to do with the oddness of the degree or the function.

Comment: So I can assume $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$ for $k=-1$ and  $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$ for $k=1/2$? and compute the coefficients ?

Comment: No, it is $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$ in both cases. Rename the coefficients of the second series to $b_n$ if it helps. The general solution will have the form $c_1x^{-1}a(x^2)+c_2x^{1/2}b(x^2)$ where $a,b$ are power series. // You can of course interleave the terms of both series as you are trying to, but in my opinion this is more trouble than it is worth, as the degrees of the terms do not align in the same way.